# Populating combobox from named ranges

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have created three dependent drop down lists using excel's validation formula. 
[image]
The benefit of this is that it is easy to add more options and the dropdown list updates automatically. The structure for this is seen below (where each range is given the same name as the column header).

[image]

Is it possible to create the same effect using combo boxes. I can find examples of populating a combo box from hand but not automatically from named ranges

Comment: Are you using listboxes on a worksheet or on a userform? If on a worksheet, are they Form Controls or ActiveX controls?

Comment: I was going to do it on a worksheet using form controls but there is no specific reason to choose one over the other. The dropdown lists I have at the moment are purely cells with a data validation formula in it

Comment: In both cases, you'd have to use VBA to get the comboboxes to populate properly, it's just a matter of which combobox you want to use.  If you want to do this with only named ranges, then the data validation is the way to go, and I see no reason to change what you're doing now.

Comment: So is it not possible to get comboboxes populating in the same way of data validation? The benefit is that you can have actions occurring when you click the options while this isn't as smooth with data validations

Comment: It is very possible to get comboboxes populating in the same way, it would just require VBA for a change event.  For Form Controls, right click it and assign a macro and then click New to have it create a subroutine for the Change Event.  For ActiveX controls, in Design Mode, right click the combobox and select View Code to have it create a subroutine for its Change Event.  Then code whatever you want in the change event (such as populating other comboboxes based on selected value to mimic dependent drop-down lists)

Comment: should you choose the Form combobox way you may find an example of setting and cross-updating comboboxes in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229880/vba-excel-userform-with-comboboxes-filter-down-and-write/36232525#36232525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can practice with.

### Create Combobox1

Populate with a worksheet_selection Change event, the headers range is named "Headers"

[image]

The range below the headers are named according to the header names.

### Populate combobox2

[image]

Change combobox1 to populate combobox2

### The Code

### Goes into the worksheet module.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim s As String
    s = ComboBox1
    Me.ComboBox2.List = Range(s).Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ComboBox1.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("Headers"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

i know this is an old post but i found this out by trial and error and wanted to share this with you guys.

when you create a namedrange and want to use that info in your combobox then i have a simple solution here.

for example namedrange is called in your case "Headers"
then do the following

```
Me.combobox1.RowSource = "Headers"
```

I don't know why but its adding the info from the named range.