# Looping through activeX ComboBoxes on a worksheet and assigning named range to listfill

Tags: excel, vba, loops, object, combobox

I have columns A and B. Each cell in column B contains an activeX `ComboBox`. What I want is for the `ComboBox` in column B to populate in reference to a named range from a different sheet based on the input in column A (directly next to the combo box)

To do this I need to run a loop through each `ComboBox` on the worksheet with nested IF statements, but cannot figure out how to loop through the combo box objects and then assign a named range to the combo box if other conditions are true.

For simplicity, cell A1 would be next to `ComboBox1`. Cell A2 would be next to `ComboBox2` etc.

Basic example:

```
myRange1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ranges").Range("NamedRange1")
myRange2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ranges").Range("NamedRange2")
i = 1

For Each ComboBox on ActiveWorksheet

If Cell("A" & i) 'condition1 here' Then
ComboBoxi.ListFillRange = myRange1
i = i+1
Elseif Cell("A" & i) 'condition2 here' Then
ComboBox'i'.ListFillRange = myRange2
i = i+1
Else 'do nothing

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a cleaner way to do this. I did not realize that you do not have to specify the worksheet for the named range even though the ranges are on a separate sheet.In this example, `"Range1"` and `"Range2"` are on their own worksheet. Also, it works without declaring the `ComboBoxes` as Objects. `ComboBoxes` are left to the default names of `ComboBox1`, `ComboBox2`, and `ComboBox3`.
Came to this solution via [Populating combobox from named ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429846/populating-combobox-from-named-ranges)

I'm sure there would be a good way to loop this instead of making a unique `if` statement for each unique cell in `Range A1:A3` and associated `ComboBox`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim result As String
Dim search1P As String
Dim search2P As String

search1P = "1P"
search2P = "2P"

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A3")) Is Nothing Then 'if target is within range A1:A3

result = Target.Value ' set result variable equal to whatever the target cell value is

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then 'if cell A1, evaluate cb1

    If InStr(UCase(result), search1P) <> 0 Then 'if result variable contains "1P" then
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "Range1" 'Populate cb1 with "Range1"
    ElseIf InStr(UCase(result), search2P) <> 0 Then 'if result variable contains "2P" then
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "Range2" 'populate combobox with "Range2"
    Else: ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "" 'leave cb blank if source cell is invalid
    End If

ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then 'if cell A2, update cb2

    If InStr(UCase(result), search1P) <> 0 Then 'if result variable contains "1P" then
    ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "Range1" 'Populate cb1 with "Range1"
    ElseIf InStr(UCase(result), search2P) <> 0 Then 'if result variable contains "2P" then
    ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "Range2" 'populate combobox with "Range2"
    Else: ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "" 'leave cb blank if source cell is invalid
    End If

ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3")) Is Nothing Then 'if cell A2, update cb3

    If InStr(UCase(result), search1P) <> 0 Then 'if result variable contains "1P" then
    ComboBox3.ListFillRange = "Range1" 'Populate cb1 with "Range1"
    ElseIf InStr(UCase(result), search2P) <> 0 Then 'if result variable contains "2P" then
    ComboBox3.ListFillRange = "Range2" 'populate combobox with "Range2"
    Else: ComboBox3.ListFillRange = "" 'leave cb blank if source cell is invalid
    End If

End If

End If

End Sub
```